# EXIF getAttributes return null

Tags: android, exif

I'm attempting to list off all exif attributes associated with an image in the gallery. Every getAttribute() returns null. When I debug and inspect the ExifInterface it has a valid file, and when I expand the "mAttributes" node the "Table" contains all of the EXIF data I'm looking for, but the "values," "keySet" and "valuescollection" are null. Any idea where I'm going wrong?

Edit: Perhaps the problem is with how I'm obtaining the file name? I've updated the code below to give a more complete picture.

```
//create an array of thumbnail IDs
String[] ids = {MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID};
//this pulls the file locations
cursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, ids, null, null, MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.IMAGE_ID);
colIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID);

//at this point we need to target the gridview.
GridView gallery = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
//borrowed an adapter provided in the tutorial at http://mihaifonoage.blogspot.com/2009/09/displaying-images-from-sd-card-in.html
gallery.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

//now we attach a listener to our gridview.
gallery.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position, long id)
    {
        String[] ids = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
        cursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, ids, null, null, null);
        colIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToPosition(position);
        String image = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA));
        ExifInterface clicked = null;
        try {
            clicked = new ExifInterface(image);
    } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

        if(clicked==null)
        {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext() , "We were not able to load the file." , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else
        {
        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.messageCenter);
        String message;
        message = "Latitude: " +  clicked.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LATITUDE)  + "\n";
        message += "Longitude: " + clicked.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE) + "\n";
        message += "Make: " + clicked.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_MAKE) + "\n"; 
        message += "Model: " + clicked.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_MODEL) + "\n";
        message += "Date/Time: " + clicked.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_DATETIME) + "\n";
        message += "Flash: " + clicked.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_FLASH) + "\n";
        message += "Flocal Length: " + clicked.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_FOCAL_LENGTH) + "\n";
        message += "White Balance: " + clicked.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_WHITE_BALANCE);

        tv.setText(message);
    }
}
});
```

Here's what clicked looks like at runtime
[image]

Edit: I found that calling the values listed in the table works. However, if I expand mAttributes.table.[0].value.value the other information I'm looking for is listed in a char array. Why isn't that information getting passed along?

Comment: This probably isn't your issue, but shouldn't those constants be `ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LATITUDE` instead of `clicked.TAG_GPS_LATITUDE`?

Comment: I tried that too. I also tried using the constant's value, so for example TAG_MODEL's value is "Model." No dice there either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some pictures work fine - so the problem was the data, not the class or my code. I suspect some devices/applications encode their exif data in a non-standard way that ExifInterface cannot parse.

Comment: Yes really. It's a pain from Google Android OS.

Answer (score 2):

You have to be suspicious of any software you use to edit the images. Even if it is just a "viewer" that you use to save it in a different format. Some will mangle the EXIF, some will strip it alltogether. Also, even though you would think that EXIF is a standard, there are wide variations among manufacturers how precisely they implement and name the tags. There is a tool called [ExifTool](http://owl.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/) that you can use not only to dump the EXIF, but also to modify and standardise it. Maybe you can embed that into your process flow or call it from your code.